# Twitter feed autoscroll

Tags: twitter, autoscroll

I have an embedded twitter feed on my page, the user can scroll down, but I would like it to autoscroll. I was thinking it could be added in the code but am not sure where to start. Please help..

```
 <TwitterBox>
                    <Timeline
                        renderError={(_err) => <p>Could not load Twitter</p>}
                        dataSource={{
                            sourceType: 'profile',
                            screenName: 'vehicle',
                            width: "100%",
                        }}
                        options={{
                            height: '700',
                        }}


                    />
                </TwitterBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have an answer to your question. Another person made this code so the credit will go to that person. Here is the code you might want to try.

```
scroll=window.setInterval(function(){window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);},1000);
```

#### Instructions

Open the profile. You want to scroll down to the end in your browser. Then open _inspect element+ mode (in the Chrome browser, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to get into the inspect mode), and then click on *console* tab and paste this code and hit enter:

```
scroll=window.setInterval(function(){window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);},1000);
```

As soon you hit enter, you will see a unique number below your posted code line. It can be 139, 43, 123, or any number. We will use this number to stop our scrolling once we reached to the profile end, as the above code will keep executing even you reached at the last post.

To stop scrolling down, simply copy paste the below code in the console and hit enter. Make sure to replace your number here with the number you get in your console when you hit enter for the first time.

```
clearInterval(your number here);
```

Example:

```
clearInterval(3085);
```

[image]

Comment: "Another person made this code so the credit will go to that person."—who wrote that code? To ensure they get that credit, please be sure to at least acknowledge their name.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer in this thread helped me a lot with this, I found it was better to use the scrollBy method, especially with options as it lets you adjust the behavior of the scroll.

```js
scroll=window.setInterval(function(){window.scrollBy({
top: 10,
left: 0,
behavior: "smooth",});},100);
```